# Pandas overwrite based on column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframes:

df1

```
index  | colA  | colB
0          a       1
1          b       2
2          a       9
```

df2

```
index  | colA  | colB
5          a       3
8          c       4
```

I want to update df1 based on df2, meaning for all rows "i" such that

```
df1['ColA'].iloc[i] == df2['colB'].iloc[i]
```

The index do not match so .update() does not work here.

Desired output:

df1

```
index  | colA  | colB
0          a       3
1          b       2
2          a       3
```

Comment: Seems like you want a mapping by colA?

Comment: @YOBEN_S I don't think this is `merge`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with boolean indexing:

```
idx = df1['colA'].values == df2['colA'].values
df1.loc[idx, 'colB'] = df2.loc[idx,'colB'].values
```

Comment: Getting KeyError: False using the above

Comment: works with the sample data on my computer. make sure you have the correct column name.